# How check if model value is defined without controller (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

I would like to know wether it is possible to check if a value is defined using only angularJS, without using a controller (or other Javascript-code). How to make that appear in the paragraph-tags below? Or is that not possible without a controller?

```html
  <body>
    <input type="number" ng-model="myTest" ng-init="myTest=0">
    <p>{{myTest*2}}</p>
    <p ng-if='true'>myTest is defined</p>
    <p ng-if='false'>myTest is not defined</p>
  </body>
```

Comment: Why do you need it, what is the difference where it was defined?

Comment: I want to know if some basic validation can be done without a controller. I don't need to know how it can be done WITH a controller.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some alternatives and what I find so far is it can be done as follows (test for null-value) but no functions (like typeof, isDefined) can be used in the html-file without using a controller. Is that correct?

```html
<body>
    <input type="number" ng-model="myTest" ng-init="myTest=0">
    <p>{{myTest*2}}</p>
    <p ng-if='myTest!=null'>myTest is defined</p>
    <p ng-if='myTest==null'>myTest is not defined</p>
  </body>
```